# Steam doesn't show MW2 or TF2 in library on different computer

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I'm trying to install my steam games (and play hopefully) on a different computer.  I installed steam, logged into my account and for some reason, it only shows Portal.

I only have three games through steam.  I have Portal, Moderwarfare 2, and Team Fortress 2.  Is there anyway that I can get them to show so I can install them?  I'm trying to switch computers completely and would rather not have to leave them both up just so I can play these games.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys, as it turns out, I accidently somehow logged into the wrong account.  I tried my normal username and password and it logged me in.  Apparently, I was using the wrong username.

Sorry for stealing points from you guys.  I really am.

Thanks for the consideration and help though :)

Answer (score 2):

In your steam window, when you have Library selected it will have your games listed.

Above the list should be a drop down menu that you can click, it probably is set on "Installed" since you only see Portal.

Change the option to "All Games" and it will list all the games that are bound to your account so you can install them.

Answer (score 2):

In the upper left hand corner, next to the search box, is a drop down that lets you filter your Steam library.  Is this set to All Games?  If it isn't, then your library will be limited by whatever the current value is.

Team Fortress 2 is "free to play" so anyone can install it by going to the [Team Fortress 2](http://store.steampowered.com/app/440/) page on Steam.  If you had the free to play version on your old PC, it might not show up on your games list on the new machine until you've installed it.

Also, this new machine is also a PC?  If you are moving to a Mac, I don't believe Modern Warfare 2 is supported on that platform.